# mysql find next date after given

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to retrieve a record with the nearest date to a given date variable?

For Example:

The date today is `Thursday, 10th January 2012`

My database has a list of fixtures from which i want to list "next week's" fixtures which are next Wednesday i.e: `Wednesday, 16th January 2012`

How do i get a file to output all rows which have this in their date column?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

This is my table with sample data -  `bowl-track_fixtures` :

```
| fixture_id | league_id | fixture_team_1 | fixture_team_2 | fixture_date             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2         | 5              | 6              | Wednesday, 30th January  |
| 2          | 2         | 4              | 1              | Wednesday, 30th January  |
| 3          | 2         | 2              | 3              | Wednesday, 30th January  |
| 1          | 2         | 5              | 6              | Wednesday, 06th February |
| 2          | 2         | 4              | 1              | Wednesday, 06th February |
| 3          | 2         | 2              | 3              | Wednesday, 06th February |

etc..
```

I want the system to only show me the rows which are nearest and after to today's date.

I have tried the following;

```
SELECT * FROM `bowl-track_fixtures` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`fixture_date`, '%l, %d%S %F %Y') >= NOW() ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`fixture_date`, '%l, %d%S %F %Y') LIMIT 1;
```

this however returns no results

@Nicarus

This is the MySQL code i am using:

```
SELECT fixture_id, MIN( STR_TO_DATE(
fixture_date,  '%l, %d%S %F %Y'
) ) AS  `next_fixture_date` 
FROM  `bowl-track_fixtures` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(
`fixture_date` ,  '%l, %d%S %F %Y'
) & gt ; = NOW( ) 
GROUP BY  `fixture_id`
)b ON ( a.`fixture_id` = b.`fixture_id` ) 
AND (
STR_TO_DATE(
a.`fixture_date` ,  '%l, %d%S %F %Y'
) = b.`next_fixture_date`
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And it returns this:

```
MySQL said: 

#1305 - FUNCTION db.STR_TO_DATE does not exist
```

Comment: Are your dates actual dates, or are they strings in that format?

Comment: Nearest or nearest AND greater date?

Comment: strings in that format i use strtotime to convert in my php files

Comment: @Nicarus nearest date only

Comment: @DavidPassmore - So if the nearest date occurs prior to the date you are passing in, that is OK?

Comment: @Nicarus i see what you mean in that case it would be nearest and greater because it would always be in theory next weeks fixures to be outputed

Comment: So, if there is more than one record with the same date and that date is the next date - would you want to only show one record or all of them?

Comment: @Nicarus I would want to get all of them preferably

Comment: Yea, you need to specify that because the `LIMIT 1` that everyone is providing in their answers will prevent you from getting any more than one record...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying this:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    `bowl-track_fixtures` a
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        fixture_id,
        MIN(STR_TO_DATE(fixture_date, '%l, %d%S %F %Y')) AS next_fixture_date
    FROM
        `bowl-track_fixtures`
    WHERE
        STR_TO_DATE(fixture_date, '%l, %d%S %F %Y') >= NOW()
    GROUP BY
        fixture_id;
    ) b
    ON  (a.fixture_id = b.fixture_id)
    AND (STR_TO_DATE(a.fixture_date, '%l, %d%S %F %Y') = b.next_fixture_date);
```

This will return the nearest and greater ("next") date for the fixture. If there are multiple with the same date, it will return them.

Two assumptions that I have made, so it's possible you need to tweak this slightly:

1. The date format of your string. Make sure that is correct or else you may get 0 records.
2. The grain at which you are determining the "next" date. I assume it is at the `fixture_id` because the date is named `fixture_date`.

Comment: i get the following `FUNCTION db.STR_TO_DATE does not exist`

Comment: You're using MySQL, right? Does it give you a line # for the error?

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using MySQL and, if so, which version? You update contains a script that is not what I posted and will not accurately return what you are seeking.

Comment: Yes I am and All MySQL versions from 3.23.32 till 5.0 (except for 4.1.0 and 4.1.1) are supported by my servers

Comment: I think that `STR_TO_DATE` only works on versions *later* than 4.1.0.

Comment: i am using the server's version which is the one i have specified and the error is `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-track_fixtures a
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        fixture_id,
        MIN(STR' at line 4 `

Comment: Add tick marks ` around the table name `bowl-track_fixtures`. See my update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22498/discussion-between-david-passmore-and-nicarus)

Comment: @DavidPassmore - Sorry, my work's proxy blocks chat. This really isn't that difficult if you have a fairly good understanding of T-SQL. I would suggest you read up some more and pay attention better to the error messages as it seems you are ignoring some very helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

Just select where date is greater than:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(yourdatecol, '%l, %d%S %F %Y') >= NOW() ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(yourdatecol, '%l, %d%S %F %Y') LIMIT 1;
```

Should work, but it's untested

EDIT: changed the STR_TO_DATE format to `%l, %d%S %F %Y`

Comment: @keeg Thanks, quick question is it that simple, because my dates are stored as strings?

Comment: @keeg: The format's not quite right, though (as compared to the examples in the question).

Answer (score 1):

use

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE yourdatecol >= NOW() order by yourdatecol LIMIT 1;
```

- `order by` will give you the latest date
- `limit` will restrict you to only one row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(t.datestring, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS ORDER_DATE ,*
FROM t 
WHERE
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(t.datestring, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') >= NOW()
ORDER BY
       ORDER_DATE DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

For more information please kindly refer ==> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

**Tested Code**

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `dates`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `dates`
--

INSERT INTO `dates` (`id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'Wednesday, 30th January 2013'),
(2, 'Wednesday, 30th January 2013'),
(3, 'Wednesday, 30th January 2013'),
(4, 'Wednesday, 06th February 2013'),
(5, 'Wednesday, 06th February 2013'),
(6, 'Wednesday, 06th February 2013');

<?php

    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die(mysql_error());
    $database   = mysql_select_db('stackoverflow')or die(mysql_error());

    $query = "SELECT
                STR_TO_DATE(date, '%W, %D %M %Y') AS ORDER_DATE,dates.*
            FROM 
                dates
            WHERE
                STR_TO_DATE(date, '%W, %D %M %Y') >= NOW()
            ORDER BY
                ORDER_DATE ASC
            LIMIT 1;";
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<table width='100%' border='1'><tr><td>ID</td><td>DATE</td></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['ORDER_DATE']."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

**don't forget to add year in mysql datestring.**

Comment: Yea, but your `ORDER BY` is on a string value, not a date, so it may not  order it correctly.

Comment: @DipeshParmar Thanks, but this returns no results... :(

Comment: from your updated question i think problem is in STR_TO_DATE(`fixture_date`, '%l, %d%S %F %Y'). Because in order to covert string in date you must have year in string means in your table record must be like "Wednesday, 30th January 2013" or "Wednesday, 30th January 2012" or whatever year is.